# Should Service Workers update on push or sync according to W3C spec?

Tags: google-chrome, standards, service-worker, web-push, samsung-browser

In the article “[Fresher service workers, by default](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/06/fresher-sw)”, Jeff Posnick mentions:

> Every time […] a service worker is "woken up" via a push or sync event, the browser will, in parallel, request […] updates to the service worker script.

Is it actually part of the W3C Service Workers Spec? I can’t seem to find it in the current Nightly draft.

Since when this has been supported by Chrome? How about other browsers?

Comment: It’s not part of the Service Workers spec — it’s in the Push API spec. For the high-level details, see https://w3c.github.io/push-api/#push-message and https://w3c.github.io/push-api/#pushframework and

Comment: Thank you @sideshowbarker for pointing me out to the Push API spec. However, I can not find any explicit mention of when exactly and event-triggered update of the Service Worker will be requested. The only uses of the word _“version”_ refer to the spec itself…